# Toggling div requires 2 clicks. Should be 1 click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got some good help here on hiding a div on mobile, but there is an additional issue I have. I am starting to learn more JavaScript, definitely a newbie.

This is a working example of a content div that is hidden on mobile unless a button is clicked. It works fine, except it takes 2 clicks to initially open the div. I want it to be only one click.

I’ve seen some answers on this type of question, and have tried them but they are beyond my ability to understand right now. I’m not getting it.

How would I rework my script so that it only takes one button click to open the div? Thanks!

```js
function toggleGallery() {
  var x = document.getElementById('image-gallery');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#image-gallery {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#image-gallery li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #image-gallery {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="toggleGallery()">Click to view images</button>
  <p>I want to reveal this content on mobile with just one button click. </p>
  <div id="image-gallery">
    <ul>
      <li>Image 1</li>
      <li>Image 2</li>
      <li>Image 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Comment: Is jQuery an option or do you want to stick with vanilla javascript?

Comment: Place `console.log(x.style.display)` before the if statement, and see what it logs to console on that first click.

Comment: nurdyguy-jquery is an option, I might use it but I want to at least understand what I'm doing with this simple stuff first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `toggleGallery()` function, replace the condition `x.style.display === 'none'` with `x.style.display !== 'block'`.

The `display` property is initially not equal to `none` meaning your function will then set it to `none` in the condition, meaning next time it will function properly and set it to `block`. By rather checking that `display` is not equal to `block` it will work the first time.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `x.style` only returns the **inline style** of `#image-gallery`. Since it has no inline style to begin with, `x.style.display` will always evaluate to undefined.

What you want is actually to get the computed display property of the element (i.e. the one you see in the developer tools under "computed styles"). To get that, you can simply use [`window.getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), i.e.: `window.getComputedStyle(x).display` instead:

```js
function toggleGallery() {
  var x = document.getElementById('image-gallery');
  var xDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(x).display;
  if (xDisplay === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#image-gallery {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#image-gallery li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

#image-gallery {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="toggleGallery()">Click to view images</button>
  <p>I want to reveal this content on mobile with just one button click. </p>
  <div id="image-gallery">
    <ul>
      <li>Image 1</li>
      <li>Image 2</li>
      <li>Image 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Comment: Thank you Terry for explaining that to me, this works. Chris' option worked too, I'm marking that one but this was extremely helpful. Now I have two ways to go at something like this--thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

set `x.style.display = 'block';` at start `style` property don't see that css rules

Answer (score 0):

Here, you had bad CSS

```js
var x = document.getElementById('image-gallery');

function toggleGallery() {
  x.style.display = x.style.display === 'none' ?
    "block" : 'none';
}
```

```css
  #image-gallery {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#image-gallery li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #image-gallery {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="toggleGallery()">Click to view images</button>
  <p>I want to reveal this content on mobile with just one button click. </p>
  <div id="image-gallery">
    <ul>
      <li>Image 1</li>
      <li>Image 2</li>
      <li>Image 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```